# How to remove jerky movement on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, debugging

I'm a developer for my fathers website. Yesterday, I made this custom cursor with vanilla Javascript and CSS : https://codepen.io/ZellRDesign/pen/PoqzgZX

After development, I tested it on my webapp.

Firefox : no problem, the code works very well and it is pretty awesome.

On Chrome : here I got my first problem, sometimes the custom cursor is jerky and I don't know how to reproduce this bug...
I got this bug only one time, but today, I share my code to friends and one of them say me "look the code is bugging"

**Example of bug :** https://i.imgur.com/PW3zCb1.gifv

So now, I have two questions :

how to patch the bug ?

and

how to improve the code to make it better ?

Thanks for help

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY - 10) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - 10) + "px;")
})

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cursor.classList.add("expand");

  setTimeout(() => {
    cursor.classList.remove("expand");
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  //cursor: none;
  background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #FAB313;
  ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation: cursorAnim .5s infinite alternate;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 8px solid #FAB313;
  ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  animation: cursorAnim2 .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes cursorAnim {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(.7);
  }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim2 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(.4);
  }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.expand {
  animation: cursorAnim3 .5s forwards;
  border: 1px solid #1E2648;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me in Chrome (79)

Comment: @JeremyThille , i don't know why , but this bug had random appaer , that's why is difficult to debug.. Maybe 1/10 times

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Chrome 80.0.3987.87. Can you find out how to reproduce it more? Is it related to clicking or just movement?

Comment: @Boris That's one of my problems : i don't know how to reproduce , i got it only one time and now , only my random friends says me "it is bugging"
the bug is only on movement

Comment: You mentioned the code runs in a "webapp", is this just a webpage or do you have it embedded somewhere else? Did you ever see the bug in the codepen or only your "webapp"?

Comment: @Boris i have seen the bug one time on my webapp , and a friend one time on codepen, the gif is from codepen bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't reproduce the issue on Chrome I think you could try to improve the overall performance by both using the `transform` property to move the cursor (instead of `top` and `left` properties) and the `will-change` property.

Since you are already using that property for the pulse animation I've inserted a a wrapper element and I've applied the `transform` there

```js
const cursorW = document.querySelector('.cursor-wrapper');
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
   cursorW.setAttribute("style", 
        "transform: translate("+(e.pageX - 10)+"px, "+(e.pageY - 10)+"px)")
})

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
   cursor.classList.add("expand");

   setTimeout(() => {
      cursor.classList.remove("expand");
   }, 500)
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    //cursor: none;
    background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}


.cursor-wrapper {
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform .25s 0s;
}

.cursor {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #FAB313;;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: cursorAnim .5s infinite alternate;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor::after {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 8px solid #FAB313;;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: .5;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    animation: cursorAnim2 .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes cursorAnim {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(.7);
    }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim2 {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(.4);
    }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim3 {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(3);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.expand {
    animation: cursorAnim3 .5s forwards;
    border: 1px solid #1E2648;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor-wrapper">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

In the CSS the `.cursor-wrapper` class is defined like so:

```
.cursor-wrapper {
   will-change: transform;
   transition: transform .25s 0s;
}
```

The `transform` will take benefit from the GPU acceleration and the `will-change` property will let the browser know that this property is going to change (I've inserted it also on `.cursor` class)

Also the JS code is applied now to the `.cursor-wrapper` class.

Finally, feel free to change the animation speed.

Comment: Your code is pretty cool but the click animation is removed .. :/

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Seems a bit buggy on click

Comment: Move the mouse and click multiple times. The dot is jumping

Comment: sorry I don't see nothing different. I'm using chrome

Comment: but also on firefox I can't see nothing different between the two examples. To be honest I haven't noticed strange behaviours anyway

Answer (score 1):

I modified your pen a little, it probably works as you need: https://codepen.io/bhoodream/pen/yLNJWEj

The main point you have problems with is moving with the `top/left`. There is a `transform` for such tasks, in your case you need `translate3d`. Here is an article on the topic: [Animating movement with translate3d](https://www.oreilly.com/content/animating-movement-with-translate3d/).

Comment: Thanks , how to add the lag follow mouse effect now ?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I decided that the lag is not needed =)
I updated the pen by adding a transition!

Comment: edit: your idea is  pretty cool but now  can't interact with link  (click doesn't work) and some bugs with the cursor:pointer :/

Comment: It is difficult to predict what you need, I solved the problem with the jerky behavior, if you provide all the necessary information on the task, maybe I will help you with the bugs.

Comment: I'm here to warn you that the code is not working properly, but I was able to correct this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the warning, you are very kind!

Comment: `poniter-events: none` on the `.cursor` do the job =)